# Apply function to specific row in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe of which I want to clean up a specific row, in this case the first row. I have written a function in which I believe will return the string if the regex is matched.

```py
def clean_cells(string):
    if '201' in string:
        return re.findall('201[0-9]', string)[0]
    else:
        return string
```

I want to apply this function to the first row in the dataframe then replace the first row with the cleaned up version then contatenate the rest of the original dataframe.

I have tried:

```py
df = df.iloc[[0]].apply(clean_cells)
```

Comment: Hi, please [provide a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select first row by position and all columns with `:` and assign back:

```
df.iloc[0, :] = df.iloc[0, :].apply(clean_cells)
```

Another solution:

```
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].apply(clean_cells)
```

Comment: Not complaining, just out of curiosity (I'm fairly new on SO): Is it normal to re-post an existing answer minutes later? Personally, I would delete mine if I noticed that it already existed...

Comment: @mcsoini - Sorry, do you think your answer is same? I think not.

Comment: @jezrael How is it not the same? there is some spurious visual noise (the colon) in yours, and some in mine (the list, which however is in line with the OP's suggestion). Apart from that, I'd be curious to know

Comment: @mcsoini - hmmm, just tested and if try it, your solution not working, but my yes (sure, it is different)

Comment: @jezrael I don't understand what you mean. Could you please comment on my example and how that is not working?

Comment: @jezrael ... and how yours does something else?

Comment: @mcsoini - How tested `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['car', 'train', 'e-bike'], 'B': ['100', '20/r25', '10/r21'], 'C': ['EUR', 'EUR/rUSD', 'EUR/rGBP'], 'D': ['T', 'F', 'F']})

clean_cells = lambda x: x[0]`

Comment: `df.iloc[0, :] = df.iloc[0, :].apply(clean_cells)`  and then `df.iloc[[0]] = df.iloc[[0]].apply(clean_cells)`